# Maximum number of lines allowed in Joomla! section

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

We maintain a Joomla! 1.5 based website. The website has a 'section' which contains 2495 lines of codes. Today when we are trying to add a few lines of codes, it is not getting saved.

I want to ask if the Joomla! section has a limit as to how many lines of codes it can save?

A code snippet

```
    <div class="t">
        <div class="b">
        <div class="l">
            <div class="r">
            <div class="bl">
                <div class="br">
                <div class="tl">
                    <div class="tr">
                                    <div class="publisher">Published by XYZ</div>
                    <div class="indexPartners">Indexed with Google Scholar, DOAJ </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If I include any further lines, it does not save. If I modify existing lines, it saves properly. The last line is line number 2496

Comment: You do know that Joomla 1.5 has some terribly bad security flaws, and you should consider upgrading as soon as possible... When you say lines of codes, are you talking HTML or CSS? Are you getting any error messages in the Admin when you try and save? As far as I know, there is no 'limit' of how many lines of code you can have on a Joomla page.

Comment: Yes Lee, thanks. We know the disadvantages of 1.5 and we plan to migrate but not before next year. I am referring to HTML. There is no error. Only the new lines are not getting saved. Further, sometimes a couple of existing lines are also truncated, the next time the section reloads after saving attempt.

Comment: Are you able to show an example?

Comment: @Lee: I have added a code snippet

Comment: Well I would also suggest maybe trying to clean up your article content? Maybe it could be down to the editor you're using that's stripping out the HTML code you're inserting?

Comment: Only from knowledge. You could turning off the WYSIWYG editor, and just typing your pure HTML into the editor box, and see if that makes a difference. Or, my suggestion would be to maybe try and incorporate your HTML code into your template files, and try to keep your content editing to just text.

Comment: @Lee: Actually I even tried to directly insert using the PHPmyAdmin panel but the same problem is being encountered.

Comment: Hmm that is a point, it could be the limit of the input of the MySql input. Thinking about it... 2500 is ALOT of lines that you're trying to save as one article. You really should condense.

Answer (score 1):

It could very well be that it's reaching the limit given by MySQL for text inputs. This is stated from the official reference:

> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 65,535 (216 – 1) characters.
>   The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multibyte
>   characters. Each TEXT value is stored using a 2-byte length prefix
>   that indicates the number of bytes in the value.
>
> An optional length M can be given for this type. If this is done,
>   MySQL creates the column as the smallest TEXT type large enough to
>   hold values M characters long.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

If this is the case, try reducing your content to get rid of unwanted elements and tags, such as those div classes you've got in your excerpt. They don't look like they're really needed.

Comment: I guess that might be the problem